# Photoshop Action to Make Coloured Shapes from Swatch Library

Tags: adobe-photoshop, swatches

This might be a bit farfetched for Photoshop, but I was wondering if there was the possibility of creating an action to make 42 rectangles by sourcing the colour from 42 swatches in the Swatches Library.

So let's say we have three swatches in our Swatches Library (red, blue, green), would you be able to create an action that created three rectangles in those three colours?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think an action is going to cut it for this, but it could certainly be scripted. What version of Photoshop? Mac or Windows?

Comment: OK, I will build you a quick script for this, but it will be a couple of hours. I'm pretty swamped this morning.

Comment: @TunaMaxx Oh, you're awesome! I really appreciate the help. THANK YOU!

Comment: I still plan on doing this for you, but today has been a gong show. I will give it a whirl as soon as I can.

Comment: Well, this is a little embarrassing. either it's been a long day and I'm a bit on the dim side, or Photoshop doesn't expose the Swatches pallet to javascript. I'll keep looking and if I can find anything I'll let you know.

Comment: @TunaMaxx That's okay, dude! No worries if you can't.

Comment: Im interested in doing the exact same thing as mentioned above. Even though it's been a while, did you guys come up with a script? I currently working on Windows.